# How these kind of illustrations are made?

Tags: vector, illustration, raster, painting

https://www.behance.net/gallery/62784931/Desire-to-lose-weight
https://www.behance.net/gallery/54576131/Editorial-illustrations-Jan-October-2017
https://www.behance.net/gallery/32957589/Sketch
https://www.behance.net/gallery/65089225/Stanley-Park-Brewing
https://www.behance.net/gallery/66061121/Identity

These kind of flat minimalist illustrations are seem to be in trend for recent years. Mostly Facebook and Google uses them often. Also I make such illustrations for my company. But I initially thought they are made in pure vector. So it takes me hell lot of time to make these in vector and to add the shadows and effects specially.
So my question is how these illustrations are normally made? Vector or Raster Painting or Vexel?

Also on a side note, although not mandatory, I will be very grateful if you share a few resources about these illustrations.

Comment: Clear vector illustrations with some texture screen mode applied on top, or irregular scatter brushes simulating a coarse airbrush. More and more new-retro style.

Comment: Some of these links list the tools used on the right side of the screen which may be helpful (usually seems to be Illustrator, Photohop or a mix of both)

Comment: All but one of these were primarily Adobe Illustrator work, one was done primarily in Adobe Photoshop: all could have been done *entirely* within Affinity Designer. ***All*** these illustrations look like thoroughly thought out, carefully composed and designed, well executed illustrations, and will probably have taken *considerable* time, either for that individual illustration or for the illustrator to establish a precursor style and workflow: they ***don't*** look to me like they can be 6-step recipe or filter or script emulated. ***TL;DR:*** carefully designed & illustrated, that's how!

Answer (score 3):

It's really up to the artist but most often its at least finalized in a raster image editor (Adobe Photoshop, Krita, Corel Paint for example). Some artists will work across a vector platform (Adobe Illustrator or Affinity Designer), but many in this genre don't bother.

Adobe has featured many artists and guides working on similar styles through their YouTube channel: https://www.youtube.com/user/AdobeCreativeCloud/search?query=Illustration

Depending on how involved you get with your layers will determine the best way to apply texture. I've seen demonstrations where the artist literally does the entire illustration on one layer, others where they methodically create new layers. If you create new layers then you can use various texture brushes (or create your own) and simply clip it to the layer beneath so it doesn't leave the edge.

Ultimately these do take a lot of time, technique, and practice to get good at and even longer to then get efficient at.